# SFML on Clion with CMakeList freetype.lib

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml, clion

i want to create a 2D game in c++ with SFML but it don't work here [my CMakeList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F5XP.png) and here [my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxP6J.png)

i think the issue is that the fill "freetype.lib" is missing but i don't know where i can find it

Comment: ***but i don't know where i can find it***  It won't be on your PC unless you put it there. You need to install it. You can build it from source or use vcpkg

Comment: If you type freetype in here it gives you the vcpkg instruction: [https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html) The instructions on how to install vcpkg are here: [https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/README.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/README.md)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect both code and error message to be in the **question post** as **text**, not linked as image. Please, (re-)read [ask] and edit your question post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [SFML CMake Template](https://github.com/SFML/cmake-sfml-project), which will automatically build SFML for you and thus ensure that freetype.lib is also available.

On Windows, SFML ships with the freetype library directly, but you need to make sure that you copy everything over from the archive you've downloaded.

If you stick with your own CMake script, you may also want to use an absolute path for `SFML_DIR` as CMake usually doesn't like relative paths.